# PHP login scrpt

Tags: authentication

I am getting folowing error when I try to execute the php following the error message on browser. kindly help me in solving this.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/includes/functions.inc.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

This means at line 5 there is a string that is out of context. Possibly you have unescaped quotes? `"fred said "have a nice day.""` should be `"fred said \"have a nice day.\""`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use same quotes inside quotes like inside " " don not use " "

```
"hello,"rohit""
```

will cause problem

use it like `'hello,"rohit"'`